# r different panels histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to draw several plots with R, but I'm new to it.
My data looks like this:

```
Item    Count   Type

Apple   118 A

Orange  63  A

Pear    126 A

Plum    193 A

Lemon   240 A

Peas    46  B

Beans   87  B

Carrot  171 B

Onion   123 B

Poatato 35  B

Cheese  44  C

Eggs    13  C

Ham 31  C

Fish    10  C
```

And I want to make a different histogram for each type of item (A, B and C) plotting the count values.
I managed to plot overlapping histograms:

```
ggplot(myfile, aes(x= Count, fill = Type))+ geom_histogram (binwidth = 10, alpha = 0.5, position = "identity")
```

But I wanted to know if it is possible to plot separate histograms, as many as different types exist in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
data <- read.table(text="Item    Count   Type
Apple   118 A
Orange  63  A
Pear    126 A
Plum    193 A
Lemon   240 A
Peas    46  B
Beans   87  B
Carrot  171 B
Onion   123 B
Poatato 35  B
Cheese  44  C
Eggs    13  C
Ham 31  C
Fish    10  C",header=TRUE) 

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x= Item, y = Count, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Type, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is called 'faceting'. Try:

```
 ggplot(myfile, aes(x= Count, fill = Type))+ geom_histogram (binwidth = 10, alpha = 0.5, position = "identity")+facet_grid(~Type)
```

And read the help for all the faceting functions in the `ggplot` documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In case it is useful to someone: I used the split function to create a variable for each "Type" and then plot it. It may be a prehistoric method, but it worked for me.